# What is this word? Why is it difficult for me to identify?

Tags: word-request, spoken-english, listening

I couldn't identify the last word "...  it can be very_____", the guy says in this audio file? Here's the [link](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1tmsRM7J2Lv).

From the OP's comment:

They are talking about Food Testers and here it goes "the thing is food testing is not a fun experience and it can be *********** ". I believe the word means something like daunting or exhausting task yet I never heard it before and I cannot find it online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for audio transcription.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I hate to break the news, but language *IS* audio.

Comment: @Araucaria: I don't see your point. Language is also writing; that doesn't mean we're an OCR service. Any attempt to use ELL as a mechanical turk for transcribing words is equally bad, since it teaches nothing to anyone.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's just not true. A good answer here would point out that there's a syllabic /n/ there instead of a vowel and point out that /t/ sounds different when it has an nasal as opposed to aural release. They would then be able to hear the word properly, and this kind of info will help them recognise other similar words too. In addition the OP and many other readers will almost definitely have learned a new bit out vocab and also know what it sounds like in fluid speech. Nothing unuseful about that.

Comment: @Araucaria: That's great (assuming that you've accurately captured the essence of the asker's problem, which is not certain, since I see no trace of what they thought the word sounded like), but how exactly is another learner with the same problem ever going to find this question? There's nothing to search for! A class of questions that can never be searched for is a class of questions that SE does not and should not handle.

Comment: @NathanTuggy"What they thought the phrase sounded like" is a bit of a weird way of putting it, given that they couldn't determine what they were hearing. But "syllabic" /n/, nasal release, *monotonous*, etc in the title would all help future readers.

Comment: @Araucaria: So, you're expecting future readers to know what they are hearing in order to search for an answer about what they are hearing, but *not* expecting the same from the question asker? I'm sorry, this isn't making sense to me. Nothing you've so far given shows any way for this question asker, or anyone in the same situation, to realistically construct a question or search that will get them to this answer without simply getting a one-off answer from whoever sees their question, again and again.

Comment: @NathanTuggy As I said "nasal release" or "syllabic n" would be good titles for learners to search under.

Comment: @Araucaria: I doubt very much anyone is searching for those terms. Neither shows up in any question on ELL; "syllabic <letter>" shows up exactly once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is [monotonous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monotonous).

It means "always the same, so boring".